# How to stop page reloading in jQuery from button click

Tags: jquery, button, reload

Here, my code reloads after every 10000 ms. Now, I need to add a button (id=button1) click function that will stop this page from reloading. But this following code is not working.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var t=0;

        if(t==0) {
            window.setInterval(function () {
                location.reload();
            }, 10000);
        }

            $("#button1").click (function() {
                t=1
                alert(t);
            });

        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Can we assume the syntax error is just a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var t=0;

if(t==0) {
```

Well, that's silly.  `t` will *always* equal `0` on that line because the line *just before it* set that value.  So let's get rid of that unnecessary part and simplify the code:

```
window.setInterval(function () {
    location.reload();
}, 10000);

$("#button1").click (function() {
    // what to do here?
});
```

Now you're setting the interval and defining a click handler.  In that click handler you want to [*clear* the interval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval).  You can do this with the value *returned* by `setInterval`.  For example:

```
var i = window.setInterval(function () {
    location.reload();
}, 10000);

$("#button1").click(function() {
    window.clearInterval(i);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. This answer was really helpful :)